# jQuery get result of .insertBefore

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Task:

- Insert a Element into the Dom **before** a specific Element
- Return that **new inserted** Element as a jQuery object
- The new inserted Element can not have an Id or anything, the only reliable information to select it is that it was inserted before that other specific Element

Inserting the Element is easy with the .insertBefore method:

```
var result = $('#myInsertPosition').insertBefore('<div>newInsert</div>');
```

That gives us a Dom like this:

```
<div>newInsert</div>
<div id="myInsertPosition"></div>
```

But `result` in this case is still the `#myInsert` Div but I need the `newInsert` Div.

How can I get the new inserted Div as jQuery object?

Thoughts are with .prev() or other selectors but I can't find a reliable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`insertBefore()` does return the newly inserted jquery object but your call is backwards, you want to do:

```
var result = $('<div>newInsert</div>').insertBefore('#myInsertPosition');
```